# Double or triple dots in "..and, oh yeah! IT'S FREE!"?

Tags: grammar

The title says it all. The context/layout on my site:

```
[introduction of a program] 
[big download button] "
..and, oh yeah! IT'S FREE!"
```

Do I need to put three or two dot's infront of "and". Or is the whole sentence incorrect?

Comment: [Ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)

Comment: There aren't any punctuation conventions for speech. And this is intended to be speech. In any event, there are no general standards for the use of the ellipsis marker. But you could use the Unicode 20206 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS character '**…**'. I'd suggest leaving a space on either side of it. I.e, " … and, oh yeah!"

Comment: There is no such thing as a two-period ellipsis. In fact I'd go so far as to say there is no such thing as exactly two periods in a row, ever. If you can produce a singe book, scientific paper, or newspaper article that uses exactly two periods in a row, please do cite it. If you can't, then there's your answer right there. Do not do something nobody else ever does.

Comment: If the asker did not know that this punctuation mark is called an ellipsis, it would be difficult for them to look up the answer in a commonly available reference. Therefore, this question should not have been closed as "off-topic." It should be reopened, and then protected.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Oxford English Dictionary, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be three dots, which together are called an *ellipsis.*  The meaning of them is that something is being left out or *elided.*  In this case, what is being left out is the implied earlier portion of a conversation you are having with the reader.